# Vui CLI 3 как, куда и что делать?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, scss, консоль

Хелп, ребят, устал шуршать документацию т.к. все равно не могу найти ответ (+ ничего в этом не понимаю, а там постоянно ссылаются на webpack и тд...). Появилась необходимость переходить на CLI, а я привык когда все как на пикрелейтед [image: собственно сам пикрелейтед] (разными файлами и ты в html все подключаешь). Объясните, пожалуйста, человеку который с сборщиками и фреймворками не работал что и к чему, или юсфул ссылочек для нубов накидайте. Заранее спасибо! (проект у меня имеется, но где и как там кодить я хз)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

У Vue лучшая документация из известных мне JS фреймворков. Плюс очень качественно переведена на русский. Вы бы хоть попробовали один или два раза прочесть, прежде чем вопросы задавать.
Вот [ссылка](https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/guide/) на русскоязычную доку по VueCLI.

Comment: Уже штрудировал документацию, но там постоянно отсылаются к webpack, в  котором я нулёвый, а пытаясь разобраться я только насобирал больше вопросов. Видосы, статьи, офишиал мануалы везде написано сложным для меня языком, я же просто прошу объяснить попроще или подкинуть статью аля "CLI для умственно отсталых". Вооот, а ответы на уровне "RTFM" я порошу не оставлять, все таки и дуракам помощь нужна.

Comment: Может тогда стоит сформулировать нормально вопрос, а не писать "где и как там кодить я хз"? Ну как на такой вопрос ответить? Сядьте, подумайте что именно вызывает вопросы и возвращайтесь с конкретикой.

Comment: Понял, принял и извиняюсь за неточную формулировку. Моей основной загвоздкой является непонимание принципов компонентной верстки в Vue CLI.  Например я не понимаю как внедрять туда семантику, как подключать внешний scss (и вообще как правильно подключить что-то извне чтобы Vue не ругался) и как внешний scss будет компилироваться, что делать с файлами которые выходят после запуска билда ну и вообще основы вестки в Vue CLI 3 (чем отличаюсь от обычной). Потому что для меня этот подход оказался слишком тяжким в освоении после обычной верстки. Был бы очень благодарен хотя бы за любую информацию.